# Why Oracle Apex not caching regions?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an apex 20.1 application with Server Cache enabled for a Page as well as regions :

Page Cache :

[image]

Regions Cache :

[image]

But when running the application, nothing is cached.

In debug I'm getting :

```
...Region not found in cache, render region dynamically
```

How can I enable cache in Apex?